# How to automatically reload the viewdidload?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have in my application a view "settings" with switches. I would like to create a function that modifies the background color of another view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write in your code of another view where you want to change colour

> viewWillApear call every time when your view is being appearing

```
override func viewWillApear(){
 super.viewWillAppear(true)

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // change your parameter

}
```